# How to count percentage row by row with multi-index

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe of roughly 30 million rows:

```
ID         DATE                         STATUS      

123        2017-01-04 18:08:56+00:00    True        
           2017-01-04 18:09:56+00:00    True        
           2017-01-06 19:12:30+00:00    False       
           2017-01-07 19:12:30+00:00    False       
           2017-01-08 19:12:30+00:00    False       

401        2017-01-01 18:08:56+00:00    False       
           2017-01-02 18:19:56+00:00    True        
           2017-01-05 09:15:30+00:00    True        
           2017-01-06 12:12:30+00:00    False
```

I'd like to count the percentage of True value for each ID row by row. The value should increase or decrease depending on the status of the current row.

I'm terrible at describing but the result should look similar to this:

```
ID         DATE                         STATUS      VALUE(%)

123        2017-01-04 18:08:56+00:00    True        100
           2017-01-04 18:09:56+00:00    True        100
           2017-01-06 19:12:30+00:00    False       66.66
           2017-01-06 19:12:30+00:00    False       50
           2017-01-06 19:12:30+00:00    False       40

401        2017-01-04 18:08:56+00:00    False       0
           2017-01-04 18:09:56+00:00    True        50
           2017-01-06 19:12:30+00:00    True        66.66
           2017-01-06 19:12:30+00:00    False       50
```

Comment: So I was thinking of something like this: For ID 123, the first status is True, then it's 1/1(100%), the second one is also True therefore it's 2/2 (still 100%), whereas the third, fourth and fifth ones are all False so they are 2/3 (66%), 2/4 (50%), and 2/5 (40%) respectively. If the following status is True then it became 3/6 (back to 50%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), multiple by `100` and if necessary round:

```
a = df.groupby(level=0)['STATUS'].cumsum()
b = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1

df['Val'] = a.div(b).mul(100).round(2)

print (df)
                               STATUS     Val
ID  DATE                                     
123 2017-01-04 18:08:56+00:00    True  100.00
    2017-01-04 18:09:56+00:00    True  100.00
    2017-01-06 19:12:30+00:00   False   66.67
    2017-01-07 19:12:30+00:00   False   50.00
    2017-01-08 19:12:30+00:00   False   40.00
401 2017-01-01 18:08:56+00:00   False    0.00
    2017-01-02 18:19:56+00:00    True   50.00
    2017-01-05 09:15:30+00:00    True   66.67
    2017-01-06 12:12:30+00:00   False   50.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
df['p'] = df.groupby('ID')['STATUS'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum()/(x.index-x.index.min()+1)).mul(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.groupby('ID').apply(lambda dd:dd.reset_index(drop=True)
                        .assign(col2=lambda dd:dd.STATUS.cumsum()/(dd.index+1)*100))\
    .droplevel([0]).pipe(print)

    ID                       DATE  STATUS        col2
0  123  2017-01-04 18:08:56+00:00    True  100.000000
1  123  2017-01-04 18:09:56+00:00    True  100.000000
2  123  2017-01-06 19:12:30+00:00   False   66.666667
3  123  2017-01-07 19:12:30+00:00   False   50.000000
4  123  2017-01-08 19:12:30+00:00   False   40.000000
0  401  2017-01-01 18:08:56+00:00   False    0.000000
1  401  2017-01-02 18:19:56+00:00    True   50.000000
2  401  2017-01-05 09:15:30+00:00    True   66.666667
3  401  2017-01-06 12:12:30+00:00   False   50.000000
```